# media query css pantallas chicas

Tags: css, mediaqueries

Tengo un pequeño dilema: Estoy desarrollando una pagina. Entonces, en pantallas chicas (como las de las nuevas Macs) no se ve bien: los textos se mueven y todo. Entonces use media queries, nada más que el navegador no me está reconociendo la que estoy usando para ese tamaño de pantalla:

```
@media (min-width: 890px) {
    #int1{
        top: 27%;
        margin-left: -38%;
    }

    .fondoNS1{
        float: right;
        width: 60%;
        z-index: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 108px;
        right: 0px;
    }

    .bottomImg{
    top: 40 ;
    }

    .btnFuturo{
        top: 25%;
        left: 61%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .btnPresente{
        top: 56%;
        left: 63%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .btnPasado {
        top: 80%;
        left: 63%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .int299 p{
        margin-left: 391px;
    }
}
```

¿Cómo se tiene que usar las medias para pantallas mas chicas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El media query que estás usando (`min-width: 890px`) indica que las pantallas con resolución **mínima** de 890px verán los estilos del media query (es decir, de 890px **en adelante**). Si querés especificar estilos para pantallas con resoluciones menores a 890px, el media query que debés usar es `max-width: 890px`.

Te dejo la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) sobre media queries para que puedas leer más al respecto y ver las reglas con las que se aplican.